# Manipulate Data Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, worksheet, consolidation

I am trying to use a simple formula across multiple worksheets (within the same workbook) to effectively consolidate data.

Current Formula: `=COUNTIF('5-01-20:5-29-20'!A:A, "Laptop")`

Basically, look at all of the cells in the 'A' columns on sheet named '5-01-20' through sheet named '5-29-20' and count the cell if it contains the word 'Laptop'

This formula returns a #Value error, as does the same formula using a [named range](https://superuser.com/questions/350370/combine-multiple-excel-ranges-across-worksheets).  A quick Google search suggests that the `CountIF` function cannot use this type of range.  Is there another solution I can try that isn't combining all of the data onto a single worksheet?

I have also tried a PIVOT Table, but was unable to get it to contain more than one Table/Worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a list of the worksheets then refer to that list using INDIRECT() and wrap the whole in SUMPRODUCT.  So for example if your list of sheet names is in Z1:Z29:

```
=SuMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Z1:Z29&"'!A:A"),"Laptop"))
```

Comment: I copied the formula over and placed the names of the sheets in the Z1:Z29 range on the sheet I'm trying to consolidate on, but I get a #REF error.

I'm not understanding the Indirect function well enough to manipulate it, are you able to expand on your answer?

Comment: @Fred: Try `="5-"&TEXT(ROW(),"0#")&"-20"` in Z1 and copy down to Z29. BTW old `CountIf` works also.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Very clever, I didn't know you could do that directly like that.

However, I am still getting the #Ref error in Scott's formula for SumProduct.  I tried using Indirect by itself to see the value that it returns and get the same error.

Comment: @VBasic2008 CountIF works perfectly on a single table range, but I can't figure out how to break that range across multiple worksheets.

Comment: @Fred: Everything is working fine on my end. You have to have all the worksheets named exactly like in cells `Z1:Z29` or what ever range you have chosen. One mistake and the formula fails. From your `#REF` error I would conclude that at least one of the sheet names is wrong or is maybe missing. Look in to this. In older versions you cannot use `A:A` so try e.g. `A1:A1000`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: That did the trick!  The range accidentally got formatted as a date and the leading 0's dropped off.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @VBasic2008 thanks for the assist.  I was called into a meeting.